# How should I create a "should store in Redis cache" abstraction?

Tags: azure, caching, architecture, redis, domain-driven-design

This is a code snippet from the [Pluralsight Azure scalability class.](https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/azure-highly-scalable-web-applications/table-of-contents)

I would like to define a policy for what should be (and what should not be) stored in the Redis cache.  Some abstract examples of a cache policy would be

- After a date
- Between dates X and Y
- Ticket popularity
- Machine Learning ...

What approach should I take to cleanly define a policy that can be implemented globally, and updated regularly?

**CloudContext.cs**

```
    public async Task<List<Event>> GetLiveEvents(DateTime currentDate)
    {
        string year = currentDate.Year.ToString();
        var key = GenerateLiveEventsKey(year); 

        var yearEvents = await cache.GetFromCacheAsync<List<Event>>(key, async () =>
        {
            List<Event> events = new List<Event>();
            string partitionKey = year;

            TableQuery<EventRead> query = new TableQuery<EventRead>().Where(TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, partitionKey));
            var result = tableEvents.ExecuteQuery(query);

            foreach (EventRead nosqlEvent in result)
            {
                var eventObj = nosqlEvent.ToEvent(false);
                events.Add(eventObj);
            }
            return events;
        });
        return yearEvents.Where(e => e.EventDate >= currentDate).ToList();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A quote from a [DZone article](https://dzone.com/refcardz/getting-started-domain-driven):

> Use the specification pattern when there is a need to model rules, validation and selection criteria.

This seems to be the case in your requirements, so go grab a look on [Martin Fowler's paper](http://martinfowler.com/apsupp/spec.pdf) on the `Specification` pattern. It really gets powerful when you combine it with the `Composite` pattern to create a fluent API for describing various rules.